# does gh-pages requires travis.yml?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying push my changes into gh-pages/index.html but it was failed,

The PR located https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-archivelibrary/pull/20

However travis-ci documentation https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Building-Specific-Branches

> By default, the gh-pages branch is not built unless you add it to the
>   whitelist.

I don't exact reason why travis-ci is started building gh-pages, do i need add .travis.yml to gh-pages or are there anythin i was missed here https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-archivelibrary/tree/gh-pages

Comment: No, Travis is not required for most of GH Pages build. Are you uploading simple static html webpages or are you using Jekyll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the build that failed was run on a different branch named `doc-update`, which we wouldn't block by default, as it's not named gh-pages

What we can do this by enable our setting to only run builds on branches that have a .travis.yml file on them, shown in below screen cast

[image]